# read CSV file and validate column which on the basis of UTF-8 character

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode, utf-8

I have to read a CSV file which is containing columns (PersonName, age, address) and I have to validate the the PersonName. 
"PersonName may only contain UTF-8 characters."

I am using python3.x so cant use decode method after opening the file.

Please tell me how to open and read the file so that PersonName who is not containing any UTF-8 character can be ignored and I can move to next line for validation.

Comment: Why can't you use `decode`?

Comment: So what is the encoding of the rest of the fields? ASCII? Something else? Usually, the whole _file_ has a single encoding, and a violation of that single encoding means the data is corrupt, and you can't really trust it. Keep in mind, a field containing solely ASCII characters is _also_ legal UTF-8 (UTF-8 is an ASCII superset).

Comment: I am not bothered about rest of the field. I have a CSV file and I just want to validate that PersonName should only contain UTF-8 character.

Comment: @ AChampion when we open the file , python3.x return unicode. so I cant use decode methode on a unicoded data.   in Python3.x string.decode() does not work

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Thanks for replying. Well I agree usually whole file has a single encoding. But I just want to verify the PersonName is having only UTF-8 character.

Comment: @user3990393: Well, either of the options given in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39801097/364696) should cover that. Python makes it possible to decode potentially garbled data without throwing exceptions, so you can use that to allow Python to do all the work for the fields where UTF-8 isn't required, leaving you to check only the key fields where it's unacceptable. The first option is lossy, but fast, and if non-UTF-8 should be thrown away, it's simplest. The second option is lossless (for rows where `PersonName` is UTF-8), and just slightly more complex.

Comment: Please provide a small sample of the data with a valid and invalid PersonName so we don't have to guess at your file format.  Showing some code attempting to process the file and any errors you get would also show us that you are attempting to do your own homework or earn your own pay.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of the file requires no checking or is UTF-8 legal (which includes ASCII data), you can `open` the file with `encoding='utf-8'` and `errors='replace'`. This will change any invalid bytes (in UTF-8 encoding) into the Unicode replacement character, `\ufffd`. Alternatively, to preserve the data, you can use `'surrogateescape'` as the `errors` handler, which uses private use Unicode codes to represent the original value in a way that can be undone later. You can then check for those as you go:

```
with open(csvname, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace', newline='') as f:
    for PersonName, age, address in csv.reader(f):
        if '\ufffd' in PersonName:
            continue
        ... PersonName was decoded without errors, so process the row ...
```

Or with `surrogateescape`, you can ensure any non-UTF-8 data (if that's "possible") in the other fields is restored on write:

```
with open(incsvname, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogateescape', newline='') as inf,\
     open(outcsvname, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogateescape', newline='') as outf:
    csvout = csv.writer(outf)
    for PersonName, age, address in csv.reader(f):
        try:
            # Check for surrogate escapes, and reject PersonNames containing them
            # Most efficient way to do so is a test encode; surrogates will fail
            # to encode with default error handler
            PersonName.encode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            continue  # Had non-UTF-8, skip this row

        ... PersonName was decoded without surrogate escapes, so process the row ...

        # You can recover the original file bytes in your code for a field with:
        #     fieldname.encode('utf-8', errors='surrogateescape')
        # Or if you're just passing data to a new file, write the same strings
        # back to a file opened with the same encoding/errors handling; the surrogates
        # will be restored to their original values:
        csvout.writerow([PersonName, age, address])
```